# I defined a prototype funciton of Array, nut it gives me a error when I called it

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I defined  a prototype funciton of Array, but it gives me a error when I called it.

```js
Array.prototype.bublleSort = function() {
  console.log(this)
}

[1, 23, 4].bublleSort()
```

The console shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bublleSort' of undefined". It is anywhere wrong?

Comment: Add a semicolon after you define the function.

Comment: Missing semicolon (;) after function.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot a semicolon, so the interpreter sees your code as:

```js
Array.prototype.bublleSort = function() {
  console.log(this)
}[1, 23, 4].bublleSort()
```

It's using the comma operator inside bracket notation, but functions have no such property as `4`:

```
Array.prototype.bublleSort = function() {
  console.log(this)
}[4].bublleSort()
```

simplifies to

```
<someFunction>[4].bublleSort()
```

But functions have no `4` property.

Always put semicolons at the end of statements - it's not good to rely on Automatic Semicolon Insertion, it's too easy to forget and run into bugs.

```js
Array.prototype.bublleSort = function() {
  console.log(this)
};
[1, 23, 4].bublleSort()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the compiler sees the opening of the array literal as continuing on the previous statement, since you didn't put a semicolon after the function definition.

So the compiler sees:

```
Array.prototype.bublleSort = function() {
  console.log(this)
}[1, 23, 4].bublleSort();
```

Accessing a non-existent property on the function returns `undefined`, hence you get an error.

Add a semicolon after the function to make it treat them as two separate statements. Semicolons are important!